# Showing date even zero value SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have SQL Query:

```
SELECT Date, Hours, Counts FROM TRANSACTION_DATE
```

**Example Output:**

```
     Date        | Hours | Counts
   ----------------------------------
   01-Feb-2018   |   20  |   5 
   03-Feb-2018   |   25  |   3 
   04-Feb-2018   |   22  |   3 
   05-Feb-2018   |   21  |   2 
   07-Feb-2018   |   28  |   1 
   10-Feb-2018   |   23  |   1
```

If you can see, there are days that missing because no data/empty, but I want the missing days to be shown and have a value of zero:

```
     Date        | Hours | Counts
   ----------------------------------
   01-Feb-2018   |   20  |   5 
   02-Feb-2018   |    0  |   0
   03-Feb-2018   |   25  |   3 
   04-Feb-2018   |   22  |   3 
   05-Feb-2018   |   21  |   2
   06-Feb-2018   |    0  |   0 
   07-Feb-2018   |   28  |   1 
   08-Feb-2018   |    0  |   0
   09-Feb-2018   |    0  |   0
   10-Feb-2018   |   23  |   1
```

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to generate a sequence of dates.  If there are not too many, a recursive CTE is an easy method:

```
with dates as (
      select min(date) as dte, max(date) as last_date
      from transaction_date td
      union all
      select dateadd(day, 1, dte), last_date
      from dates
      where dte < last_date
     )
select d.date, coalesce(td.hours, 0) as hours, coalesce(td.count, 0) as count
from dates d left join 
     transaction_date td
     on d.dte = td.date;
```